# pspictures are gone when I change the class

Tags: pstricks, document-classes, auto-pst-pdf

The following code works fine and displays a square between two strings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}
aaaa
\begin{pspicture}(25,25)
\psset{unit=1mm,linecolor=black}
\psframe(0,0)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}
bbbb
\end{document}
```

However, when I change the first line to:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{lipics}
```

the "aaaa" and the square are not displayed.

lipics is the [class file of Leibniz International Proceedings in Informatics](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/styles/lipics/lipics-authors.tgz).

I understand there is probably some problem with the cls file.  How can I debug it?

Comment: do you get no error in the log?

Comment: No errors.. the pictures are simply gone.

Comment: Odd I downloaded the file and tried it and got an error but I see Herbert has provided the solution, I got `</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   1   0   0.0   -1.19699   a   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   ......
  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{lipics}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\usepackage{pstricks}\fi
\begin{document}
aaaa
\begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
\psset{unit=1mm}
\psframe(0,0)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}
bbbb
\end{document}
```